# Syntax For Compressing script

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compress these 3 Lines into 1

```
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    
    Cells(27, 1).Select
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

My attempt was

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(27,1).Paste
```

But i was getting a error 438

> "object does not match the method or property."

Any idea how i could compile this in 1 line?

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(27,1).PasteSpecial XlAll`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: ... i.e. `Paste` works with worksheets while `PasteSpecial` works with ranges. A more efficient option is to use the `Copy` method `SourceRange.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(27,1)` which is short for `SourceRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(27,1)`.

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet2").Paste Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(27, 1)`

Comment: @Tim Williams: That's a 'new' one. I can't recall ever seeing it.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Can't say I use it much either - the `someRange.Copy Destination:=someOtherRange` is the go-to version.